# WhenAny behaving like WhenAll in certain case

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-5

So I had a problem with a third party library where the call could get stuck and never return even when calling `cancellationToken.Cancel`. The below is a prototype that take care of this situation and that it works.

```
public async Task MainAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown");
    }
}

private async Task<string> StartAsync()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    cts.CancelAfter(3 * 1000);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    cts.Token.Register(() => { Console.WriteLine("Cancelled"); tcs.TrySetCanceled(); });

    return await (await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, LongComputationAsync())
        .ConfigureAwait(false)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task<string> LongComputationAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1 * 60 * 1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return "Done";
}
```

So the Above will wait 3 seconds, and it will throw a `TaskCancelledException` like it should.
If you then change the method `LongComputationAsync` to the following:

```
private Task<string> LongComputationAsync()
{
    Task.Delay(1 * 60 * 1000).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return Task.FromResult("Done");
}
```

I would still expect this to have the same behaviour, but what this does is that, it will wait the full 1 minute (specified in the `LongComputationAsync()`) then throw the `TaskCancelledException`.

Can anyone explain this to me? On how this is working, or if this is the correct behaviour to begin with.

Comment: Well, yes of course. `LongCompuationAsync` isn't asynchronous if you block the calling thread, and it blocks the calling thread for 1 minute. When `StartAsync` calls into `LongCompuationAsync` it will get stuck on that line, and it won't even reach the first `await` until that 1 minute has elapsed.

Comment: Specifcally the call to `LongComputationAsync` does not return until after the 1 minute delay that you synchronously await and thus you basically end up calling `WhenAny` with to completed tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain this to me?

Sure. The problem doesn't have anything to do with `WhenAny`. Rather, the problem is that the code assumes a method is asynchronous when it's synchronous.

This is a relatively easy mistake to make. But as a general rule, a method with an asynchronous signature *may* be asynchronous; it does not *have* to be asynchronous.

As I describe on my blog, [asynchronous methods begin executing synchronously, just like synchronous methods](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). It is only when they hit an `await` that they may run asynchronously (and even then, they may continue synchronously).

So, the new version of `LongCompuationAsync` is synchronous, and it executes the entire method before returning the task to `StartAsync`, which then passes it to `WhenAny`.

Comment: I always taught that once you declare a function as Task, that means that that function will be ran asynchronously. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to force a Task function to run asynchronously without using an await?

Comment: @Dethras: If you mean force it to run on a thread pool thread, you can use `Task.Run`.